# Is it legal to use side-effects in exceptions thrown by constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, assert, language-lawyer, constexpr

Normally, constexpr must be free of side-effects. However, I just discovered that it is possible to use side-effects in the constructors of thrown exceptions. That technique can be used to emulate assert() for constexpr functions, as it is demonstrated in the following program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>

struct constexpr_precond_violated : std::logic_error
{
  constexpr_precond_violated(const char* msg) :
    std::logic_error(msg)
  {
    std::cerr << msg << '\n';
    abort(); // to get a core dump
  }
};

#define TO_STRING_IMPL(x) #x
#define TO_STRING(x) TO_STRING_IMPL(x)

#define CONSTEXPR_PRECOND(cond, value) \
  ((!(cond)) ? throw constexpr_precond_violated( \
    "assertion: <" #cond "> failed (file: " \
    __FILE__ ", line: " TO_STRING(__LINE__) ")")    \
   : (value))

constexpr int divide(int x, int y)
{
  return CONSTEXPR_PRECOND(y != 0, x / y);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // The compiler cannot know argc, so it must be evaluated at runtime.
  // If argc is 2, the precondition is violated.
  return divide(100, argc - 2);
}
```

I tested it with g++ 4.7.2 and clang++ 3.1. When the preconditions fails, you get the error location and a core dump.

```
./constexpr_assert some_arg
assertion: <y != 0> failed (file: constexpr_assert.cpp, line: 26)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So it works with the current compilers, but is it legal C++11?

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you supply a compile-time constant `0` as the 2nd arg to `divide()`? Does the *compiler* "throw an exception"? :)

Comment: static_assert(divide(1, 0) >= 0, "testing");

simply won't compile

    return divide(1, 0);

compiles with Clang and fails only at runtime.

Comment: You must be careful to distinguish between constant expressions and a `constexpr` function. Something like "`constexpr` must be free of side-effects" is imprecise. Think of `constexpr` as no more than a keyword (`static` comes to mind).

Comment: You can have expressions with side-effects on the subexpressions of `&&`, `||` or `?:` that are not evaluated at compile-time. There's nothing special about the constructors of exceptions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is legal.

For each `constexpr` function there must be some argument values that result in a constant expression (§7.1.5/5):

> For a `constexpr` function, if no function argument values exist such
>   that the function invocation substitution would produce a constant
>   expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Note that this does not mean that *every* possible argument value must result in a constant expression. `divide` clearly has some argument values that result in a constant expression: `divide(1, 1)` is a simple example. So, the definition is clearly valid.

But can `divide(1, 0)` be called? Yes, it can. There's almost no difference between invoking a `constexpr` function or a "normal" function (§7.1.5/7):

> A call to a `constexpr` function produces the same result as a call to
>   an equivalent non-`constexpr` function in all respects except that a
>   call to a `constexpr` function can appear in a constant expression.

Note that calls to `constexpr` functions *can* appear in constant expressions, but nothing forbids them from not resulting in constant expressions. This is intended so one can call `constexpr` functions with both compile-time and runtime arguments (otherwise usefulness of `constexpr` would be severaly limited).

For completeness, let's see what makes a constant expression (§5.19/2):

> A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless it
>   involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression
>   (§3.2), but subexpressions of logical AND (§5.14), logical OR (§5.15),
>   and conditional (§5.16) operations that are not evaluated are not
>   considered [...].

So, `divide(1, 1)` is a constant expression, but `divide(1, 0)` is not. If you used `divide(1, 0)` in a template parameter, the program would be ill-formed. But otherwise it's fine.