# Is constexpr a "hint" (like inline) or "a binding request" to the compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Is `constexpr` an indicator for the compiler or does it mandate a behaviour ?

The example at hand is the following :

```
template<typename T> 
std::size_t constexpr getID() { return typeid(T).hash_code(); }
```

`hash_code` is a runtime constant, yet this snippet would [compile](http://ideone.com/Zm2X92) even though a compile time evaluation is requested with `constexpr`. Only after the return value is used where a compile time constant is expected, would we get noticed that this [is not usable as a constexpr function](http://ideone.com/LxcuMF).

So is `constexpr` a "hint" (much like the `inline` keyword) or "a binding request" to the compiler ?

Comment: Note that because this is a template, there *isn't any function* until you instantiate it with some `T`.

Comment: In this [example](http://ideone.com/Zm2X92), you see instantiations of this function compiling

Comment: @Mehrdad thnx for the correction

Comment: `inline` isn't a hint either.

Comment: I updated the answer below, if you want tot take a look

Comment: @Charles C99 and C11 `6.7.4/5`, and C++11 `7.1.2/2` all say it's a suggestion or indication to make calls as efficient as possible, and state the example of textually inlining the function at the call site. That classifies as a hint in my book. Of course, if the hint is respected is implementation-defined...

Comment: @rubenvb: "As efficient as possible" is meaningless (well, QOI) waffle but the ODR rule changes (the real guts of what `inline` does) are a mandated behaviour change (at least in C++ which is what I was referring to in my original comment).

Comment: My understanding (no citation though) is although `inline` is specified to be a hint, your implementation is likely to have a MUCH better idea of when to inline/not inline than you and I believe they generally do what they think is sensible. My advice is to only ever use `inline` for its ODR-related behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [C++11 Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#constexpr_.E2.80.93_Generalized_constant_expressions):

> If a constexpr function or constructor is called with arguments which
>   aren't constant expressions, the call behaves as if the function were
>   not constexpr, and the resulting value is not a constant expression.
>   Likewise, if the expression in the return statement of a constexpr
>   function does not evaluate to a constant expression for a particular
>   invocation, the result is not a constant expression.

The `constexpr` specifier thus expresses *the possibility* to evaluate something at compile time and is subject to [some restrictions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) when used.

---

For your particular snippet it seems to me that the C++11 constraint:

> exactly one return statement that contains only literal values,
>   *constexpr variables and functions*

is not fulfilled, as hash_code is defined to be:

```
size_t hash_code() const;
```

In this case the [standard draft n3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) says:

> For a constexpr function, if no function argument values exist such
>   that the function invocation substitution would produce a constant
>   expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

I believe your example fits here.

Comment: So basically `constexpr` was a pointless addition to the language.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Not at all. You can still call constexpr functions with compile time constant values and they can be evaluated at compile time, too.

Comment: @user2799037: The point is not that they may be evaluated at compile time, but that they can be used for things that only accept constant expressions like template parameters or array sizes.

Comment: @user2799037: er, I didn't say it's a useless keyword. It's there because it has a use. What I said was that there was no need to add it to the language to begin with; they could have achieved it differently. They could have instead just stated that every function call be evaluated at compile-time if possible (i.e. if the result would be the same as it would be at runtime), making it unnecessary to have a keyword just for that purpose.

Comment: @Mehrdad Defining a constexpr value is guaranteed to be evaluated at compile-time and raise a compiler error if it cannot be done.

Comment: Thought: The standard could *require* compile time evaluation for all expressions that match the given requirements except the `constexpr`  tag. Result would be the same for the programmer, and the compiler would be no harder to write. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Jens: Trying to evaluate all functions at complie-time would give you the same result: If you use it where it needs to be evaluated at compile-time and it can't be evaluated at compile-time...you will get an error. So no need for a keyword..so as Mehrdad says: it's pointless!

Comment: @peterchen: That's the same thought I had above.

Comment: @RüdigerStevens I don't think it is pointless. Until now, it is not possible to create a compile-time constant of an object without workarounds like instantiating a template. constexpr explicitly allows this and makes it obvious to the reader. Until now, I would have to create a template class for compile-time constants and and use some COMPILE_CONST<T>::value to access it. constexpr jsut makes life easier, code more readable and intent more explicit. Three big gains.

Comment: @Jens: My point is, what information exactly do you think `constexpr` provides to the compiler that it could not have determined on its own?

Comment: @Mehrdad Well, for a constexpr function that would not be very much, but for a constexpr variable it means: "This has to be evaluated at compile time. Raise an error if not." I don't think any compiler could find out that this was my intent without me saying it. When you consider changing code, it can happen that changes to functions change this, and the compiler has to inform me about because I say that it has to be this way.

Comment: @Mehrdad: yeah, your first comment made me think. Now, thinking about it again, in addition to Jens' last comment: the compiler needs to test for those conditions only if constexpr is given, so this might be a necessary compile time optimization.

Answer (score 14):

> Is `constexpr` a “hint” (like inline) or “a binding request” to the compiler?

It is neither. Forget about *when* it is evaluated. Everything (with a few minor exceptions, notably involving `volatile`) is evaluated whenever the compiler deems it necessary to produce the behaviour of the C++ abstract machine. There isn't much else to say about *when* things are evaluated.

The compiler is free to produce code that evaluates what would be constant expressions at runtime if that doesn't produce a different behaviour. It is free to produce code that evaluates things not marked `constexpr` at compile-time if it has the smarts.

> If not about compile-time vs runtime, what is `constexpr` about, then?

`constexpr` allows things to be treated as constant expressions. Anything marked `constexpr` *must* have the possibility of producing a constant expression in some way.

In the case of functions, they can be able to produce constant expressions with some arguments but not others. But as long as there is some set of arguments that can result in a constant expression, a function can be marked `constexpr`. If such a set of arguments is used in a function call, that expression is a constant expression. Does that mean it is evaluated at compile-time? See above. It's evaluated when the compiler deems appropriate. The only thing it means is that you can use it in a context requiring a constant expression.

For variables, either they are constant expressions or not. They have no arguments, so if `constexpr` they always have to be initialised with constant expressions.

**TL;DR**: `constexpr` is about tagging things as being usable in constant expressions, not about deciding when to evaluate them.

---

With that out of the way, it appears your function template is ill-formed. There is no set of arguments that could result in a constant expression. The standard doesn't require a diagnostic for this, though.

Comment: See an example explanation of a function that can be produce both constant expressions and non-constant expressions, even if all arguments are constant expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13039987/46642.

Comment: `Either the compiler is buggy, or this is a compiler extension` : if  the standard didn't change from n3242 it is explicitly stated that no diagnostic is required for that kind of error

Answer (score 2):

constexpr functions can be used to evaluate compile time constants. So it is possible to use it like:

```
 constexpr int func(int a) { return a+2; }

 char x[func(10)];
```

If func is called during runtime, the compiler *can* evaluate this expression before if possible. But that is not a must but normally done if the input is also const.

It is also important to have constexpr constructors. This is the only chance to get non POD classes constexpr objects.

```
    class Point
    {   
        private:    
            int x;
            int y;
        public:
            constexpr Point( int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}  
            constexpr int GetX() const { return x; }
    };  

    constexpr Point p{1,2};

    int main()
    {   

        char i[p.GetX()];
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you expand on your point about non-POD classes? Is `const std::string hello("hello");` not a `const` instance of a non-POD class?

Comment: sorry for wrong wording. I mean *constexpr* objects! See added example!

Comment: With an aggregate type you can create non-POD objects in constant expressions without a constructor (aggregates cannot have constructors). It's not PODness that matters.

Answer (score 2):

The complete answer to your question has two aspects:

1. A constexpr function can only be evaluated at compile-time when all
   arguments can be evaluated at compile-time. It can still be used as
   a normal function which is evaluated at runtime.
2. An constexpr variable must be initialized with a value evaluated at compile-time.
   The compiler has to raise an error if it cannot do this.

You could assign the hash code to a constexpr variable and then get a compiler output:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <array>

template<typename T> 
std::size_t constexpr getID() { 

    return []() {constexpr size_t id = typeid(T).hash_code(); return id;}(); }

int main() {
    // both statement generate compiler errors
    //std::array<int, typeid(int).hash_code()> a;
    //constexpr size_t y = typeid(int).hash_code();

    size_t x = getID<int>();
}
```

Comment: What is an *initialized value*? Are there *uninitialized values*?

Comment: @dyp `int i` would be an uninitialized value because it has not been explicitly initialized by the programmer. Is there a better word for this? Maybe initialized constexpr variable?

Comment: It is not clear what a value is (as far as I know), but typically you say for `int i;` that `i` is the name of an object (an object is a region of storage) and which *stores* a value. So *uninitialized variable* or *uninitialized object* should be fine. IIRC, in C++1y, we'll get the notion of a *indeterminate value*; `int x;` not being initialized would have (contain) an indeterminate value.