# How is std::mutex's constexpr constructor implemented?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, mutex, constexpr

While looking at the C++ Reference for [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/mutex), I noticed that the constructor for `std::mutex` is marked `constexpr`.

This is surprising at first, since we usually have to make a system call (either [`pthread_mutex_init()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init) (POSIX) or [`CreateMutex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexa) (Windows)) to initialize a mutex.  However, on closer inspection, for POSIX, one can use the constant `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` to statically initialize the mutex (perhaps as a global variable), though I can find no equivalent for Windows.

However, even if this static initialization for POSIX was the reason behind the `constexpr` constructor, there're still various unsolved issues for an implementation:

1. On Windows (and perhaps other non-POSIX systems), there may not be a way to statically initialize mutexes.
2. It was impossible to have different code paths depending on whether the constructor is being called at compilation time until C++20's [`std::is_constant_evaluated()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) was added, so we don't have a way to determine if `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` or `pthread_mutex_init()` should be used.

So, how does one implement the `constexpr` constructor for `std::mutex`?

Comment: On MSVC, the mutex constructor isn't constexpr yet it is implemented as (latest visual studio 2019, full C++20 support on, /Zc:__cplusplus ).  /* constexpr */ mutex() noexcept // TRANSITION, ABI). The constructor (after 2 steps) calls into the runtime directly so I do think that indeed a CreateMutex is done there. I can think of an implementation with postponed creation of the actual OS mutex until the first lock (mutex can't be created in locked state), and maintaining the lock state using  std::atomic<bool>. std::atomic also has a constexpr constructor, (last part is me brainstorming).

Comment: @PepijnKramer That sounds like a way to implement it, yes, but making it lazy just adds overhead for no benefit as far as I can see.  That feels like an unneeded abstraction that kind of goes against C++'s design principles of giving control to the user as much as possible...

Comment: Anyway I don't know the real answer to your question :) From the standard: constexpr functions can only depend on functionality which is a constant expression. Being a constexpr function does not mean that the function is executed at compile time. It says, that the function has the potential to run at compile time. A constexpr function can also run a runtime

Comment: Yeah, but constexpr means that the function must be runnable at compile time, which rules out any kind of syscalls.  (And if you're using `std::is_constant_evaluated` you still have to ensure that the constant evaluated branch is constexpr-safe.)

Comment: Good read :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775705/is-constexpr-a-hint-like-inline-or-a-binding-request-to-the-compiler

Comment: Thanks :)  That raises another question though - does making the mutex constructor constexpr actually change anything (usability, behavior, etc)?  If you assign the mutex to a constexpr variable, then you can't actually lock and unlock it, which seems to render it useless.

Comment: Note that the standard only says the constructor is constexpr, not lock and unlock!
And I'm happy with that, I wouldn't want deadlocks during compilation ;) But yeah just having a constexpr constructor doesn't add much

Comment: @PepijnKramer: The cppreference notes say "Because the default constructor is constexpr, static mutexes are initialized as part of static non-local initialization, before any dynamic non-local initialization begins. This makes it safe to lock a mutex in a constructor of any static object.", so this makes static mutexes less surprising/fatal for constructors.

Comment: @Hasturkun That makes sense :)

Comment: With sufficiently recent Windows versions, `std::mutex` could be implemented in terms of [`WaitOnAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress) et al. This does allow for static initialization.

Comment: There is an open [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/2285) in Microsoft STL: `We believe mutex's default constructor can feasibly be made constexpr absent the need to support Vista.`

Comment: "does making the mutex constructor constexpr actually change anything (usability, behavior, etc)? " Read the cppreference page you have linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, it is possible to implement `std::mutex` as `constexpr` using `SRWLOCK`.

Unfortunately full `SRWLOCK` is available starting in Windows 7. It was introduced in Windows Vista, but without the ability to implement `try_lock` using it.

Visual Studio 2022 has dropped Windows Vista support, so it could have switched to `SRWLOCK`, but for ABI compatibility reasons, to be compatible down to VS 2015, it still uses the implementation that allowed runtime selection of sync primitive, to avoid `SRWLOCK` on pre-Win7.

Technically it is possible to implement `std::mutex` based on `CreateEvent` and lazy initialization, in Windows 95 and later, but this implementation would be complex and suboptimal, as it will not use the OS primitives directly and will not allow the OS to be aware of the mutex.

---

On POSIX, you can use `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` unconditionally, even in runtime.

Comment: So, how does Windows implement the `std::mutex` constructor?

Comment: Windows doesn't. It is MSVC that implements it. Currently it is not `constexpr` in MSVC. With the new ABI breaking release it will be though - with `SRWLOCK` and `SRWLOCK_INIT`

Comment: @AlexGuteniev it's neither Windows nor MSVC because the C++ stdlib is a separate thing and you can find the source code in https://github.com/microsoft/STL