# Why can't this mutex be constexpr constructed?

Tags: c++, constexpr

```
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    constexpr static std::mutex my_mooootex;
}
```

I get the error of:
"Initialization is not constant"

On Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022. std::mutex has a constexpr constructor, doesn't it?

Comment: Seems from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68970111/how-is-stdmutexs-constexpr-constructor-implemented) that it's another ABI break they don't want to touch yet.

Comment: Specifically it's a MSVC++ ABI break.  Your code would compile with a compliant compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It's a flaw in Microsoft's compiler.

Your code is valid.  Any compiler reporting an error with the code you show is doing so incorrectly.