# constexpr modifier has no effect

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, constexpr

I have some problem with constexpr functions.
I thought, any function declared with `constexpr` modifier *must* return compile-time constant, but actually it doesn't work. (Eclipse + MinGW, gcc 4.8.1)

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

template<typename _Ty>
constexpr _Ty test_function(_Ty x) { return x; }

int main() {
    auto x = time(0);
    std::cout << test_function(x) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, `x` is not a compile-time constant, but this code compiles well and works as if `test_function` is without `constexpr` modifier. Does anybody knows why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038985/is-it-legal-to-use-side-effects-in-exceptions-thrown-by-constexpr/13039987#13039987 is also very interesting